# Convert from Tizen::Base::FloatBuffer to std::vector<float>?

Tags: c++

There is a function that takes an `std::vector<float>` parameter. I have the values in a variable of type FloatBuffer`.

Is it possible to make such a conversion?

Comment: Retagged to C++ as this is unlikely C#.

Comment: It would help if you added some reference about the Tizen Class lib? and what you have tried to do to solve the problem.

Comment: @Caribou thanks for rply i have solved my problem by copy the data into std::vector<float>..  it works

Comment: @Sunnyshah :) glad Marc could help - you should accept his answer (click the tick).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Tizen::Base::FloatBuffer` does not seem to have any conversion methods (or iterators), so you will need to copy the data into a `std::vector<float>` first.